# I created a chat room : Epistemology

Tags: discussion

The intention of the room is to fit there any question that would not fit the Q/A of the site regarding, in particular, to epistemology.

Comment: Why? Barely anyone uses The Symposium as it is. And it appears your room has already frozen.

Comment: I didn't know how to ask a particular question, if it fit the Q/A format due to its structure, and if an appropriate chat room existed for it.

Comment: The Symposium is for general chat such as this.